# How can i re-render ngFor when data doesn't change?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

**Overview:**

I have a list that binds two arrays together with an ngfor using pipes. i bind the arrays on a typeID.

One array lists all the available types and the other holds the selected types along with an extra option. **Note** The arrays only share 2 properties, name and id

**Problem:**

Because my ngFor is bound to the first array when data changes in the second array nothing is updated so at the minute i have to recall my http method which grabs the exact same data just to update the list.

I need a way to force rerender without calling my api everytime something in the second array changes

**StackBlitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxkwaf

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpr2e6?file=src/app/app.component.ts I commented `this.getPrimary()` calls

Comment: if you check the "isChecked" checkbox first then it should select both check boxes and add to the array. Once it's added to the array then "isChecked" can be checked/unchecked multiple times

All the functionality works as it should i just need a better way of re-rendering the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tweaked version of onik's solution i managed to solve this with less lines of code

**Solution**

```
this.secondary = this.secondary.concat({ primaryID: primary.primaryID, name: primary.name, isChecked: false });
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rydedr

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ngIf** and a **setTimeout** to make the ngFor re render. Call `this.reload()` instead of `this.getPrimary()`

```
reload() {
  this.show = false;
  setTimeout(() => this.show = true);
}
```

Wrap the **ngFor** inside a **ngIf**

```
<ul class="list list-a" *ngIf="show">
   <li *ngFor="let p of primary;">
```

**Plunker** : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geuesx

Comment: this kinda feels like a hack, probably better performance than my current hack but i wouldn't mind an actual solution if there is one, thanks though

Comment: Try hiding and showing ag-grid-angular component with an `*ngIf="show"` to remove the previous instance of ag-grid using setTimeout like this `this.show = false; setTimeout(() => this.show = true)`

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer you gave above. The problem with this is i have no need to show/hide the list other than to force/hack this to work. Using a tweaked version of onik's solution i can set the object that is actually being used to update the template which is a nicer way to do it in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

you can import the `ChangeDetectorRef` from the angular core and trigger `markForCheck`. This is probably not the optimal way, but it should re-render the component in your case

Comment: could you help me out with an example of this? I have briefly looked into ChangeDetectorRef and feel you could be right here but don't know how i would implement it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set for new reference on this array and it will rerender,

```
this.secondary = [...this.secondary];
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you mean, maybe edit the stackblitz?

Comment: A pipe will rerun if any of its parameter changes, so reassigning **secondary** will rerun the pipe **isInArray** as **secondary** is a parameter of the pipe.